# ASP.NET Core handle Method Not Allowed 405

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Developing an API platform that needs to be consistent through App Service itself and covering Azure API Management Service - I found myself stuck with an inconsistencies between both.

Sending a request with improper HTTP verb (e.g. PUT instead of POST) to API Management service results with 404 Not found response ([due to a known issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/32626496-return-status-code-405-instead-of-404-when-wrong-m)).

Sending same request directly to ASP Core 2.2 based app would result in 405 Not Allowed response.

Is there any possibility in ASP Core (possibly middleware) to catch 405 response code result and change it to 404?

Comment: Too late for an anther but just for clarity. 404 means the method ist not there at all. 405 means the method is there but called with a wrong verb. That is exactly the case described here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm a fan of just doing blind status code conversion. Up to you based on your exact scenario, of course.

This bit of middleware injected in your `Configure` method would do the trick:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 405)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        return next(context);
    });
}
```

*NOTE: Add this early in the chain.*

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you can handle with the [`StatusCodePages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-status-code-pages) middleware. Here's an example:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(ctx =>
{
    if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 405)
        ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

The argument passed into `UseStatusCodePages` is a callback function that is executed whenever the middleware detects a response with a status code between 400 and 599 (with an empty body). In the example above, we simply check for `405` and change it to `404`. The call to `UseStatusCodePages` itself must be placed before any request-handling middleware, such as MVC.

Comment: Thank you,
_italic_UseStatusCodePages was the first thing I tried, but if API Versioning is used (which is producing 405 status) - in described scenario its handler delegate is never executed.

Comment: I meant scenario when _API Versioning services_ is added to the service collection and calling controller is wrapped with _ApiVersionAttribute_.
This is the reason 405 status code is returned and response payload (by default) contains following JSON: 
`{ "error": { "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion", "message": "..." } }`.
In contrast out-of-the box ASP.NET Core web app project would simply return 404 status code and empty response payload.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. If the body isn't empty the Status Code Pages middleware won't run. Thanks for the update.